# replacing a whole line of code inside a string from db

Tags: php, paypal, str-replace

```
$find1 = "<form action=\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr\" method=\"post\" target=\"_top\">";
$replace1 = "<form action=\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr\" method=\"post\" target=\"paypal\">";
$find2 = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cmd\" value=\"_s-xclick\">";
$replace2 = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cmd\" value=\"_cart\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"add\" value=\"1\">";
$paypalcartcode = str_replace("$find1", "$replace1", $qry_listItems['paypal_code']);
$paypalcartcode = str_replace("$find2", "$replace2", $qry_listItems['paypal_code']);
$paypalcartcode = str_replace("https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif","images/shop/icons/addtocart.png", $qry_listItems['paypal_code']);
echo $paypalcartcode;
```

I'm trying to replace a few lines in a paypal code through my database.
$qry string has the original code of the button since I manualy add the same code but in a Buy Now version, this one should convert it to Cart one, but the problem is that it won't even do the changes.

I asume because str_replace is not the right code to use, or maybe I wrote it wrong.
I checked through the page itself and through the code, it simply won't update the current code with the replaced ones.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you like to replace variables with the str_replace function you must call the function without the double quotes for the variables.  Try this:

```
$paypalcartcode = str_replace($find1, $replace1, $qry_listItems['paypal_code']);
```

I have tested the following code and it works fine...

```
$find1 = "<form action=\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr\" method=\"post\" target=\"_top\">";
$replace1 = "<form action=\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr\" method=\"post\" target=\"paypal\">";
$qry_listItems['paypal_code'] = "I am a text.... <form action=\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr\" method=\"post\" target=\"_top\"> .... for testing the str_replace function";
$paypalcartcode = str_replace($find1, $replace1, $qry_listItems['paypal_code']);
echo htmlentities( $paypalcartcode);
```

Comment: and you're sure that $find1 is contained in $qry_listItems['paypal_code'] ?

Comment: Yes. I already checked a few times, both $find1 and $find2 are in. the problem might be with reading the <=""> tags because the last str_replace with the paypal button works. only the two str_replace for the find and replace code parts dont. might also because there are spaces inside, which makes me think str_replace is not the right command to use